# Allow users to run my JAR reservation program online

Tags: java, jar, ftp, portfolio

Thank you for helping.

Basically I have a JAR reservation program on my desktop. What is the best way to put this on my portfolio website so prospective employers can run my program via access on my website?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option would probably be [Java Webstart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/). It allows people to run your program straight from the web, without downloading it by hand or making it an applet.